# Javascript Thumbnails Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website that displays pictures with the help of java-script. The way that I have this website set up at the moment, an image is displayed above thumbnail links. The problem is that the thumbnails are showing as broken, even though they send the correct image. Why is it doing that? Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
var photos = new Array();
var photoindex = 0;

photos[0]="images/piano.jpg";
photos[1]="images/guitar.jpg";
photos[2]="images/studio.jpg";
photos[3]="images/sheetmusic.jpg";

function backward()
{
if (photoindex > 0)
{
document.images.p.src = photos[--photoindex];
}
}

function forward()
{
if (photoindex < photos.length-1)
{
  document.images.p.src = photos[++photoindex];
}           
}

function goto(n)
{
if (n < photos.length && n >= 0)
{
photoindex = n;
document.images.p.src = photos[photoindex];
}           
}
</script>

<br>
<div style="text-align:center;left:5px;">
<table width="250" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr> 
<td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"> 
<img src="images/weloveweb.png" name="p" width="250" height="188" id="p" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><a href="javascript: backward();">&lt;&lt;</a></td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align: center"> 
<script type="text/javascript">

for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++)
{
document.write("<a href=\"javascript: goto(" + i + ");\">" + "<img src=" + photos[i] + "/></a> ");
} 
</script>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="text-align: right"><a href="javascript: forward();">&gt;&gt;</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You image `src` should have quotes

```
for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++)
{
document.write("<a href=\"javascript: goto(" + i + ");\">" + "<img src='" + photos[i] + "'/></a> ");
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/evxoko9a/

Comment: But this causes them to be full size though. How do I make them thumbnail size?

Comment: You need to either use a smaller thumbnail image or style the image to be smaller, which would be a new question. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evxoko9a/1/